# How to create a web deploy package (scwdp) for Dedicated CD Instance Option

Tags: scaling, setup

Out of box, Sitecore provides with XP0 and XP1 SCWDP packages. We are thinking that  Dedicated CD Instance option below will suffice our requirements.

https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/scaling-guide/scaling-scenarios/scale-vertically/index.html#dedicated-content-delivery-instance

This combination requires:

1. CD
2. CM (with processing and reporting)
3. xConnect (with collection & search, Reference Data, Automation etc.)

I can't find any good documents on how to create a sitecore web deploy package for such a scenario. Basically I need to know which configurations/connection setting should be enbabled/disabled for each. And how to setup web jobs as well.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I do have similar requirement. My Thought Process:
if we see the topology of XP0 single and XP1 dedicated cd instance ,the xconnect part is very similar so mixed up both XP0 and XP1 for this configuration like below CD: XP1 CD,
CM: XP1 CM,
Xconnect: XP0 Xconnect. Please post your answer it would greatly helpful to me.

Answer (score 3):

SCWPD are just zip files, so you can extract and modify them to add you adaptation.

In essence, the biggest differences for your topology are in the web.config.

Especialy in the appSettings part where the role is defined (role:define). In theory you can just reuse the XP1 package and than go into it and change the web.config.

Or you could also just use the XP1 package unmodified and override the appsettings in azure on the webapp. (or push this on azure through the ARM templates)

Comment: I am confused with the parameters.xml which come as part of the scwdp. Please help me to understand what are these for and how these to be used.